# cannot install Kurento Media Server on Cloud9-ide

Tags: cloud9-ide, kurento

Cannot get KMS ( Kurento Media Server ) to install properly on cloud9 running Ubuntu 14.04 and I tried for a long time.

When I try to start the KMS i get this response

/etc/init.d/kurento-media-server-6.0: 18: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
/etc/init.d/kurento-media-server-6.0: 20: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
 * Starting Kurento Media Server
   ...done.

There are no other obvious errors when I install it. It then doesn't exist when I try to uninstall it and when i test if it is running it is not when i grep it.

I tried to install in it on codeanywhere and on my home computer all using the standard commands from the kurento website and it installed perfectly using the standard instructions but I want it on cloud9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to change ulimits on Cloud9 workspaces. It would have to be changed on Cloud9's hosting platform so that command gets killed.

As a workaround, you can remove the `ulimit` command from the startup script located in `/etc/default/kurento-media-server-6.0`. Look for [these lines here](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-media-server/blob/7e9471024f656b6905860fb3753308f3be98e9c6/debian/kurento-media-server-6.0.default#L18). Keep in mind that commenting those might leave you running out of file descriptors.

Comment: This is  true and as far as i can tell if I could change ulimits then it would work. I am unsure if Kurento can be used on cloud9 at all and if it can be run i would like to know how.

Comment: You can remove the `ulimit` command from the startup script located in `/etc/default/kurento-media-server-6.0`. Look for these lines [here](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-media-server/blob/7e9471024f656b6905860fb3753308f3be98e9c6/debian/kurento-media-server-6.0.default#L18). Keep in mind that commenting those might leave you running out of file descriptors.

Comment: i will try that thanks a lot some great knowledge of  kms  there